# How does a CBPeripheralManager know it is connected or disconnected by a central device in Core Bluetooth?

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

On the central end, the CBPeripheral delegate would be called while connected or disconnected. But how does a CBPeripheralManager know that it is connected or disconnected by a central device? Besides, is it possible for a peripheral device to decline a connection request from a central device?

Answer (score 10):

You don't receive a specific notification when a central connects to peripheral service provided by your app.  You can infer a connection from the following `CBPeripheralManagerDelegate` methods being called -

- `didSubscribeToCharacteristic`
- `didReceiveReadRequest`
- `didReceiveWriteRequest`

If you have received a subscription via `didSubscribeToCharacteristic` then you can infer a disconnection when you receive a corresponding call to `didUnsubscribeFromCharacteristic`.  If the central is not using subscriptions then you have no indication that they have disconnected - you simply won't get any more read/write requests.

You cannot decline a connection from a central.  You can set an encryption requirement on one or more of your characteristics.  This will then initiate a pin-based pairing process when a central first attempts to read/write/notify on that characteristic.

You could also implement some form of authentication process where a central needed to respond to a challenge/write a password to a characteristic etc before you respond to that central's other read/write requests.

Comment: Hi Paulw11, thanks for your answer. But I am not sure about the connection building process initialized by central. Does it mean that the central just reads the broadcasting signals from peripheral while connecting, without notifying the peripheral as long as it does not do anything on the characteristics?

Comment: No, at the Bluetooth layer there is notification to the peripheral that a connection is being initiated and some communication takes place to establish the connection, but the Core Bluetooth framework does not expose a delegate method to advise a CBPeripheral that a connection has been made

Comment: @Paulw do you know the rational behind not exposing this information?  Also, is there some way to simulate a "bad" BTLE link (like we can say WiFi link will drop 50% of the packets using Settings --> Developer)?

Comment: I don't know why this is how it works and there is no Bluetooth link conditioner that I am aware of, although with the lower power of BLE it is probably a case of "it works or it doesn't"

Comment: For a link conditioner, just move the peripheral and central farther away. I wrote a simple app there each device is both a central and a peripheral the simply incremented a number and passed it back to the other device, displaying the number on screen. I walked with one of the devices away from the other one and watched as the update frequency slowed and eventually halted. Easy link conditioner. :)